# Could not + verb +?

Tags: verbs

Maybe related to this topic. Is there any gramatical structure for this sentence: "Could the lad not take a letter for me to the queen?" I have read it in a tale, where king requests a boy to do something for him. Is this an "order" or "plead"? (I know option 1 is more probable, but I hadn't seen a form like this.)

Comment: Perhaps "a letter **from** me..." But you mention "option 1", what is "option 2"? The sentence reads to me, as though the lad has refused to take a letter, or someone else will not let him.

Comment: @WeatherVane Actually it's "a letter for me..." I quoted it from a tale in Brothers Grimm Magic Tales (translated by David Luke). The Devil's Three Golden Hairs, page 192: "Then the king realized this was the very same fortune-child he had thrown into the river, and he said: 'Good people, could the lad not take a letter for me to the queen? I'll pay him two gold pieces.' 'As my lord the king commands,' they replied..."

Comment: @WeatherVane I used option, because I meant to say: in case the king requests, is this an "order" or a "polite request" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The construction you quote (with "could he not ...?") is definitely a polite request, not an order.

It does sound strange that a king would be so meek in his language. I thought at first it might be one of those frequent cases of a king going into his kingdom incognito, in which case he would probably act as if he were an ordinary subject, and not issue orders, but pleas.

However, looking into this, I wonder if the quote happens to be from the story "The Giant with the Three Golden Hairs", or "The Devil with the Three Golden Hairs". I read up (superficially) on a few versions of this story, and I found a few different alternative descriptions of the king's statement:

> 1) ["Wikisource](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Grimm%27s_Goblins_(1876)/The_Giant_with_the_Three_Golden_Hairs): "He is a fine fellow," said the king, "can you spare him to carry a
>   letter to the queen?
>
> 2) [From Professor Norberg, Duke Univ.](https://sites.duke.edu/adhoc_fairytalespublic/fairy-tales-by-khm-number/21-40/29-the-devil-with-the-three-golden-hairs/): He hid his vexation, however, and presently said kindly, “I want to
>   send a letter to the Queen, my wife; if that young man will take it to
>   her I will give him two gold-pieces for his trouble.”
>
> 3) [One-elevenbooks.com](https://one-elevenbooks.com/The-Devil-with-the-Three-Golden-Hairs/): He tasked the boy with taking a letter to the queen.
>
> 4) [Howardism.org](http://www.howardism.org/Mythology/Vasily.html): Years later, the king, again disguised as a merchant, was wandering
>   through the land, ... "I have an errand for the boy," said the King,
>   "if he is man enough to undertake it."

If your sentence is indeed from this story, it seems that it *is* a polite request, and the king behaves in such an unassuming manner because: **A**. He might be disguised as a commoner and/or **B**. He is trying to appear nice. (The contents of the letter are anything but nice, but he wants to lay a trap.)

Comment: thank's for your comprehensive answer. Yes, actually it's from "The Devil's three golden hairs" (translated by David Luke), and as far as I understand the king is pretending to be nice to, as you said, lay a trap.

Answer (score 0):

It is a slightly odd word order. Possibly it is an old fashioned word order. However, the meaning is the same as "Could not the lad take a letter to the queen for me?"

The sentence is structured as a question, but most likely it is a rhetorical question, implying "I think the lad can take a letter" and challenging the person he is talking to to contradict.

> — I want to send this letter to the queen but I'm too busy.  Can you do it?
>   — Sorry. I'm busy too.
>   — What about your son. He doesn't do any work. Could the lad not take the letter to the queen for me?
>   — Yes, I suppose he could.

etc.